# How do I consume a web service protected with WS-Security in mono using c#?

Tags: c#, web-services, mono, ws-security

I've got the code working that consumes an unprotected web service, but I'd like to know how to consume one using WS-Security.

A pointer to some documentation would be helpful. I just can't find a starting place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported. There has been some questions on the developer mailing list from a company willing to sponsor development of this, but they eventually did not follow through.

Comment: They're willing to sponsor development of WCF?

Answer (score 1):

Unless Mono supports WCF, there is no way to do it.